# Prestahsop : Get Manufacturers Meta Keyword on Manufacturers List

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, templating

I am maintaining a webshop on which manufacturer Meta Keywords have been used to order manufacturers on the list page : manufacturer are displayed on different part of the page depending on their meta keywords.

Recently, the page broke and all manufacturer are displayed on the same part of the page.

Investigating this, it seems that Prestashop does not load the meta_keywords anymore when loading the Manufacturers (client recently updated to 1.6.11). This would make sense as meta_keywords are mostly obsolete and rarely used - But I need them anyway for this page to be correctly displayed.

I there a was to still load and use the meta_keywords on ManufacturerList.tpl ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to get the meta_keywords, they are not selected int the function `getManufacturers`. only description and short_description are selected from manufacturer_lang.

You can change that file (not recommended because future updates can overwrite it), or create an override file in overrides/classes/Manufacturer.php
with:

```
class Manufacturer extends ManufacturerCore
{
    public static function getManufacturers($get_nb_products = false, $id_lang = 0, $active = true, $p = false, $n = false, $all_group = false, $group_by = false)
    {
        if (!$id_lang) {
            $id_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
        }
        if (!Group::isFeatureActive()) {
            $all_group = true;
        }

        $manufacturers = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
        SELECT m.*, ml.`description`, ml.`short_description`, ml.`meta_keywords`, ml.`meta_description`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m
        '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('manufacturer', 'm').'
        INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer_lang` ml ON (m.`id_manufacturer` = ml.`id_manufacturer` AND ml.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
        '.($active ? 'WHERE m.`active` = 1' : '')
        .($group_by ? ' GROUP BY m.`id_manufacturer`' : '').'
        ORDER BY m.`name` ASC
        '.($p ? ' LIMIT '.(((int)$p - 1) * (int)$n).','.(int)$n : ''));
        if ($manufacturers === false) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($get_nb_products) {
            $sql_groups = '';
            if (!$all_group) {
                $groups = FrontController::getCurrentCustomerGroups();
                $sql_groups = (count($groups) ? 'IN ('.implode(',', $groups).')' : '= 1');
            }

            $results = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
                    SELECT  p.`id_manufacturer`, COUNT(DISTINCT p.`id_product`) as nb_products
                    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p USE INDEX (product_manufacturer)
                    '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` as m ON (m.`id_manufacturer`= p.`id_manufacturer`)
                    WHERE p.`id_manufacturer` != 0 AND product_shop.`visibility` NOT IN ("none")
                    '.($active ? ' AND product_shop.`active` = 1 ' : '').'
                    '.(Group::isFeatureActive() && $all_group ? '' : ' AND EXISTS (
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg
                        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON (cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`)
                        WHERE p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product` AND cg.`id_group` '.$sql_groups.'
                    )').'
                    GROUP BY p.`id_manufacturer`'
                );

            $counts = array();
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $counts[(int)$result['id_manufacturer']] = (int)$result['nb_products'];
            }

            if (count($counts)) {
                foreach ($manufacturers as $key => $manufacturer) {
                    if (array_key_exists((int)$manufacturer['id_manufacturer'], $counts)) {
                        $manufacturers[$key]['nb_products'] = $counts[(int)$manufacturer['id_manufacturer']];
                    } else {
                        $manufacturers[$key]['nb_products'] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $total_manufacturers = count($manufacturers);
        $rewrite_settings = (int)Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS');
        for ($i = 0; $i < $total_manufacturers; $i++) {
            $manufacturers[$i]['link_rewrite'] = ($rewrite_settings ? Tools::link_rewrite($manufacturers[$i]['name']) : 0);
        }
        return $manufacturers;
    }
}
```

Then delete the file cache/class_index.php to be recreated again with the override in that file and it should have the data you need.